# Xamarin.Forms: what is the best way to create an image carousel?

Tags: xamarin, carousel, xamarin.forms

I tried coule of plug-in for image carousel for Xamarin.Forms, but they are pretty old and not working fine. Trying the carousel view from Xamarin it's pretty slow and I guess has a limitation on the number of images I can add.
Anybody know how to implement a great carousel for a list of images in Xamarin.Forms ?

Thanks !!

Comment: What Xamarin.Forms version do you use?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin.Forms version 2, I can update to the latest version if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CarouselView](https://xamarinhelp.com/carousel-view-xamarin-forms/) is the way to go. See the link for a tutorial on how to use it.

It has been removed from 2.2.0 due to stability issues and will be temporarily placed in a separate Nuget package of most likely this link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView/ within a few days.

Once it is stable it will be moved back into the main nuget package.

Comment: I think I've tried this plug-in and indeed I have removed it as I had problems. When do you think it will be fixed and live again ?

Comment: They (multiple people from Xamarin) said it would be live this week. Considering today is Friday, we should see it today and it will include a lot of bug fixes.

Comment: Is it better than their (Xamarin) CarouselView they are going to have in Xamarin.Forms ?

Comment: Its the same code, but with bug fixes and effort in stabilizing the issues. The code will be put back into the Main Nuget once they are happy its stabilized and not as buggy as its original release. And I still can't see it anywhere, will try and follow them up some more.

Comment: any news from Xamarin people about the carousel plugin ?

Comment: Nope, complete silence on the subject so far.